# Python - unpacking kwargs in local function call

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I would like to pass a `dictionary`:

```
items = {"artist": "Radiohead", "track": "Karma Police"}
```

as a parameter to this `function`:

```
def lastfm_similar_tracks(**kwargs):

    result = last.get_track(kwargs)
    st = dict(str(item[0]).split(" - ") for item in result.get_similar())
    print (st)
```

where `last.get_track("Radiohead", "Karma Police")` is the correct way of calling the local `function`.

and then call it like this:

```
lastfm_similar_tracks(items)
```

I'm getting this error:

`TypeError: lastfm_similar_tracks() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)`

how should I correct this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First problem: you need to pass `items` in like this:

```
lastfm_similar_tracks(**items)
```

Second problem, inside `lastfm_similar_tracks`, `kwargs` is a dictionary, in which the keys are of no particular order, therefore you cannot guarantee the order when passing into `get_track`. The best that you can do is:

```
result = last.get_track(kwargs['artist'], kwargs['track'])
```

At this point, the code should work the way you intended. However, I question the use of `**kwargs` in `lastfm_similar_tracks`: do you really need to define it that way? How about:

```
def lastfm_similar_tracks(artist, track, **kwargs):
    result = last.get_track(artist, track)
    # The rest of your code here
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
lastfm_similar_tracks(**items)
```

This way, you ensure that the caller must pass in `artist` and `track` or the function call will fail.

Answer (score 10):

A few items of confusion:

You are passing the dictionary `items` as a parameter  without the double star. This means that `items` is treated as the first *positional* argument, whereas your function only has `**kwargs` defined.

Here's a simple function:

```
>>> def f(**kwargs):
...     print (kwargs)
```

Let's pass it `items`:

```
>>> items = {"artist": "Radiohead", "track": "Karma Police"}
>>> f(items)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Oops: no *positional* arguments are allowed. You need to use the double star so that it will print:

```
>>> f(**items)
{'artist': 'Radiohead', 'track': 'Karma Police'}
```

This leads us to the next issue: `kwargs` inside the function is a *dictionary*, so you can't just pass it to `last.get_track`, which has two *positional* arguments according to your example. Assuming that order matters (it almost certainly does), you need to get the correct values from the dictionary to be passed:

```
result = last.get_track(kwargs['artist'], kwargs['track'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically, **kwargs in function definition means named arguments should not be unpacked to variables.

To call some function with dictionary of arguments, these still need to be represented as named parameters. Else python "considers" supplied argument to be positional

Thus, you should call you function as:

```
items = {"artist": "Radiohead", "track": "Karma Police"}
lastfm_similar_tracks(**items)
```

Comment: Note that this will still cause an error because he is passing the `kwargs` dictionary to `last.get_track`

Comment: @agg3l I had tried this. this gives me `TypeError: get_track() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: @brianpck Good point, I missed this error in sample code block