# How to define specific function parameter variables from string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm receiving JSON objects of arbitrary shape.
And reform them into Lists mapped using `__code__.co_varnames[:argc]`
Ending up with a List looking like this  `["param1=hello", "param2=world"]`
in any order.
Now I want to link them to the specific parameters in the function as below.
But can't find how. In bash we have `eval()` I read something about using `exec()` but don't know how that should work.

```
def foo(param1:str, param2:str, *args) -> str:
    return param1 + param2

list1 = ["param1=hello", "param2=world" ]
list2 = ["param2=world", "param1=hello" ]

# Want to do something like this for both lists
print(foo(*list1))
print(foo(*list2))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? None of what you describe should require messing with `__code__` or `eval`. Can you post an example of your JSON and your intended output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the function a [`kwargs` dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178978/python-unpacking-kwargs-in-local-function-call) of the form `{"param1": "hello", "param2": "world"}`. To achieve this, simply [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the strings with `=`:

```
kwargs = dict(s.split('=') for s in list1)
print(kwargs, foo(**kwargs))
```

Will give

```
{'param1': 'hello', 'param2': 'world'} helloworld
```